# List<T> Binary search returns wrong value

Tags: c#, list, binary-search

The binary search returns wrong value even though the list is sorted. Here is the list:

```
1707 ABCD
1707 XXXX
1725 DEFG
1725 HIJK
1725 LMNOP
```

I get this list from a file presorted as per the time (First column), so I don't sort this in my code. When I do a binary search on 1725 DEFG, it returns me 1725 LMNOP before a bitwise complement. If I do a bitwise complement the result would be 1725 HIJK.

Why is that ?

Here's the implementation:

```
 public class RecComparer: IComparer<MyData>
{
 public  int Compare(MyData x, MyData y)
{
    if (x.DateDetails == null)
    {
        if (y.DateDetails == null)
        {
                           return 0;
        }
        else
        {

            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if (y.DateDetails == null)
                      {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int retval = x.DateDetails.Length.CompareTo(y.DateDetails.Length);

            if (retval != 0)
            {

                return retval;
            }
            else
            {

                return x.DateDetails.CompareTo(y.DateDetails);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the call to the BinarySearch:

```
lookAhead = recordList.BinarySearch(lookAheadtime, (IComparer<MyData>)rc);
```

Any reason's why it's behaving that way.

**EDIT:**

```
public class MyData
{
    public string DateDetails { get; set; }
    public string TrackDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe binary search works with non-unique keys

Comment: what would be the best way to implement this then.

Comment: @DarrenKopp: If this is the case should I also include my second column of the list instead of just searching by first column.

Comment: You will have to reproduce the way the list was sorted.  So comparing the string length is entirely inappropriate.  You must dig out the time from the string first, like the original code did, compare that first.  Then compare the rest only if it is time is the same.  You would be well ahead by *not* using a string but parse the source first into your own class.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you please give me an example to understand this better. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the lengths to compare on first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update #2**: Binary search using a custom comparer in a list with duplicates.

Assuming that, in "1707 ABCD", "1707" is `DateDetails` and "ABCD" is `TrackDetails`, you have an array of data with two fields which is already sorted in order of *one of the two fields*, namely `DateDetails`.  Thus there may be multiple entries with the same `DateDetails`.

If you do a BinarySearch, it will return one of the entries with the specified `DateDetails`, *not necessarily the first*.  You must then scan backwards to find the first.

```
public static class ListHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the zero-based index of the first matching item in the sorted List, 
    /// if a match for item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise 
    /// complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is
    /// no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <param name="comparer"></param>
    /// <returns>The zero-based index of the first matching item in the sorted List, 
    /// if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement 
    /// of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is
    /// no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.</returns>
    public static int BinarySearchFirst<T>(this List<T> list, T item, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int start = list.BinarySearch(item, comparer);
        for (; start > 0 && comparer.Compare(list[start], list[start - 1]) == 0; start--)
            ;
        return start;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Find the zero-based indices of the first and last matching items in the sorted List, 
    /// if a match for item is found; otherwise, a negative number for both that is the bitwise 
    /// complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is
    /// no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <param name="comparer"></param>
    /// <param name="start">The zero-based index of the first matching item in the List, 
    /// if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement 
    /// of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is
    /// no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.</param>
    /// <param name="end">The zero-based index of the first matching item in the sorted List, 
    /// if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement 
    /// of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is
    /// no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.</param>
    /// <returns>true if found, else false</returns>
    public static bool BinarySearchRange<T>(this List<T> list, T item, IComparer<T> comparer, out int start, out int end)
    {
        start = end = list.BinarySearch(item, comparer);
        if (start < 0)
            return false;
        for (; start > 0 && comparer.Compare(list[start], list[start - 1]) == 0; start--)
            ;
        for (int last = list.Count - 1; end < last && comparer.Compare(list[end], list[end + 1]) == 0; end++)
            ;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I had to make one change to get it working :  for (; start > 0 && rc.Compare(recordList[~lookAhead], recordList[start - 1]) == 0; start--)
               ;

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand the problem, but can't you just use linq to search the list?

```
recordList.Where(x=>x.columnName == 1725).First();
```

Comment: no that's not the case, this is just an example above where I'm having trouble with. If I use your code with LINQ I can't search for nearest value